# Hyper-V Wifi Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04, hyper-v

I am installing hyper-v for the first time on a device that uses a wifi connection. Previous installations have used wired network adapters. I noticed after creating an external switch , the wifi adapter is bridged through the network bridge. The host works as intended.

I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and i would have expected that it would connect to the host network  using a virtual wired network adapter. Instead it says that it is offline and attempts to connect to the wireless access point.

Is this behaviour expected?